# Meaning of integral identity containing cross product with the area differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, divergence-theorem

Edit: I just noticed that the exercise itself was asked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158142/showing-iiint-r-mathbfr-times-nabla-phi-dv-iint-partial-r-mathbf) However I'm not asking for a proof, but about the meaning/intuition behind the notation / exercise itself.

On a Multivariable Calculus problem sheet I was asked to prove the following integral identity:

**Problem**. Let $f$ be a smooth scalar field defined on a region $R \subseteq \mathbb{R^3}$ with a smooth boundary $\partial R$. Show that
$$\iint_{\partial R} f \mathbf{r} \wedge \text{d} \mathbf{S} = \iiint_R \mathbf{r} \wedge \nabla f \, \text{d}V$$

I did manage to solve the problem by using the fact that d$\mathbf{S}$ = $\mathbf{n}$dS, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward-pointing normal to $\partial R$ at $\mathbf{r}$ and by applying the divergence theorem on a well-chosen vector field (I won't go into details in case this problem appears on a problem sheet in the future.)

I have two questions about this problem:

**1)** Is there some sort of meaning behind taking a cross product with the area differential, or is it in this case just a shorthand notation for $\mathbf{r} \wedge \mathbf{n}$ dS? I was very confused when I first saw it, and it seems like it's not really necessary, but why would they choose this notation if it doesn't really mean anything special?

**2)** Is there any kind of (perhaps physical or otherwise) interpretation of this integral identity, or is it just the result of some arbitrary calculation? I can't wrap my head around what it's supposed to mean...